# How do you call a function in a package via an sql query

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have got a function in PL SQL called `FUNCTION names_active(name_entity IN NUMBER)` in a package called `names_package`
how can I call it a query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT names_package.names_active(42) 
FROM dual
```

More details are in the manual:
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_packages.htm#sthref993

Comment: DUAL is a built-in table that always returns exactly one row: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries009.htm#i2054159